# VBA: ListObjects.DataBodyRange.ClearContents does not work in 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I made an excel file and filled it with macros. I developed it in 2016 but the user who will be using it works with excel 2010. (Yes I know how dumb of me)

Anyways, here's the code

```
Sub Clear()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    PubVarSet                                         'This just calls a method that sets all public objects. i.e. listobjects and worksheets
    FullReport.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    FullReport.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    Dim asd As Integer
    If FullReport.ListRows.Count > 1 Then
        FullReport.DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(FullReport.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                                     FullReport.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
    End If
    Cells(6, FullReport.ListColumns.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The entire macros work in 2016 but when im using using 2010, it gives me an error of

> Run-time Error '1004':
>   ClearContents method of Range class failed.

Any possible workarounds? TIA

edit: If youre wondering, the table has records inside

Comment: At what point do you set the FullReport object type var to the ListObject table?

Comment: Is the worksheet protected?

Comment: @Jeeped When I called in the PubVarSet method

Comment: @TinMan No protections as of now whatsoever